# What do Dread and Chivalry do?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

As far as I know, both Dread and Chivalry both increase the Public Order in a city / castle. But from my experience, I know that only Dread decreases the enemy's morale, but I'm not sure what Chivalry does. **So, what are all their effects?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In the Battlefield:

The more dread a general has, the more morale damage his troops do to the enemy's morale. On the other hand, the more Chivalry a general has, the more his troops will refuse to rout.

Essentially you either have your troops be harder to rout, or make it easier for your troops to rout the enemy.

However you can have more than one general in your army, so effectively you can get both effects (although only the leading general [who carries the horn] will receive battle-traits for that specific battle).

### In the Campaign Map

Both increase public order, if a General is appointed as Governor (Being in the Settlement). However the faction leader gets relationship penalties/bonuses if he has high dread/chivalry (respectively) towards other factions.

Ideally you want your faction leader/ faction heir to be investing in Chivalry and non-inheriting sons / other generals to be dread or a mixture. That maximizes your relations and combat effectiveness.